# AppRegistryNotReady error when when trying the tutorial from Django site

Tags: python, django

I'm trying the tutorial given on Django site. When I'm trying to run below command I'm getting error.

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
q.choice_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 228, in all
    return self.get_queryset()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 706, in get_queryset
    qs = qs.filter(**self.core_filters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 679, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 697, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1304, in add_q
    clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1332, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1144, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1030, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1367, in names_to_path
    if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 60, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 110, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Question(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return u'%s'%self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return u'%s'%self.question_text
```

This is my manage.py code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "demo.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

This is my wsgi file

```
"""
WSGI config for demo project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "demo.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong over here. I followed the tutorial, but it is breaking over here.

I'm using python 2.7.9 and Django 1.8.2

Comment: Where are you running the code? Do you use `manage.py shell` to start the python shell with django loaded?

Comment: show your wsgi file, i think there is something wrong with it or your manage.py

Comment: I'm running my code using manage.py shell only (using pydev ).

Comment: I'm not familiar with pydev. `manage.py shell` should run `django.setup()` for you. You could try to do it manually. `import django; django.setup()` to see if that fixes it.